# How to allow users to login on offline active directory

Tags: active-directory

how can i setup my Active directory running on windows 2008R2 server that allows my
client computers to be able to connect even if Active directory server is
not available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that you don't have GPO settings (or local policy) set to disable user caching. As EEAA said, it is enabled by default.

One thing to note is that it does require a given user to have logged in at least once, to have the credentials cached in the first place. You can't (to my knowledge) pre-cache a user in a workstation.

Answer (score 2):

Active directory does this by default - no special configuration is necessary to enable credential caching.

Comment: Then whats the problem if it wont cache users credentials